# Is there any other kingdom than the Mushroom Kingdom?

Tags: mario-series

In the Mario Brothers universe, We always hear about the princess Peach and the Mushroom Kingdom, but are there any other kingdoms in the Mario Brothers universe?

Comment: Arguably isn't every world from Super Mario Bros 3 a different kingdom, since each of them have a different king?

Comment: The release of Super Mario Odyssey has shown that there are many other kingdoms

Comment: Yup, seems that kindoms in Mario are variable depending on the game.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to the [*Super Mario* Wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/Category:Kingdoms) there are quite a few!

If we stick to just main series *Mario* games, you have:

- the [Beanbean Kingdom](http://www.mariowiki.com/Beanbean_Kingdom) from *Mario and Luigi SuperStar Saga*.
- [Birabuto Kingdom](http://www.mariowiki.com/Birabuto_Kingdom), [Chai Kingdom](http://www.mariowiki.com/Chai_Kingdom), [Easton Kingdom](http://www.mariowiki.com/Easton_Kingdom), [Muda Kingdom](http://www.mariowiki.com/Muda_Kingdom) from *Super Mario Land* for the Game Boy.
- [Sammer's Kingdom](http://www.mariowiki.com/Sammer%27s_Kingdom) from *Super Paper Mario*.
- [Flora Kingdom](http://www.mariowiki.com/List_of_Implied_Locations#Flora_Kingdom_) mentioned but not actually see in *Super Paper Mario*.
- [The Dry Dry Kingdom](http://www.mariowiki.com/List_of_Implied_Locations#Dry_Dry_Kingdom) mentioned in *Paper Mario*, but not actually seen.
- [Sprixie Kingdom](http://www.mariowiki.com/Sprixie_Kingdom) from *Super Mario 3D World* and *Toad's Treasure Tracker*.
- [Nimbus Land](http://www.mariowiki.com/Nimbus_Land) from *Super Mario RPG*, which although it is called a Land and not a Kingdom, does have a King and Queen.

There are also various Lands, Towns, Towers, Forests and other areas not listed here, as you were only asking about Kingdoms specifically. Donkey Kong Jungle Beat has various fruit themed Kingdoms as well. There is also the [Baseball Kingdom](http://www.mariowiki.com/Baseball_Kingdom) mentioned in *Mario Super Sluggers*.

Also as pointed out in comments, if we believe Luigi when he mentions it in *Thousand Year Door*, there is also a Waffle Kingdom.

Comment: There's also Princess Daisy from Sarasaland (not sure which game it's mentioned) and if Luigi is to be believed about his exploits during *The Thousand Year Door* there is also Princess Eclair from the Waffle Kingdom.

Comment: I mentioned the various kingdoms in Sarasaland (those are the ones listed as being from Super Mario Land)..

Comment: I take it Isle Delfino is part of the areas not listed, right?

Comment: @linkyu yeah, because it is an island, not a Kingdom per se.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Right, I was just making sure. Thanks!

Comment: "Nimbus Land is a floating kingdom on a massive cloud where cloud-people live in Super Mario RPG: Legend of the Seven Stars" ([source](http://www.mariowiki.com/Nimbus_Land)). I know Dacio covers it in his answer, but it can't hurt to have one complete answer.

Comment: Captain Toad Treasure Tracker does not actually feature Sprixie Kingdom, they only show the entrance (spoilers)

Comment: You edited in Nimbus Land? Way to steal my  •_•} .. { •_•}>⌐■-■ .. {⌐■_■} Thunder

Answer (score 9):

Yup, there are.

[Super Mario Land](http://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_Land) takes place in [Sarasaland](http://www.mariowiki.com/Sarasaland), and is the country [Daisy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Princess_Daisy) rules over.

[Super Mario Land 2](http://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_Land_2) takes place in [Mario Land](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Land_Super_Mario_Land_2:_6_Golden_Coins), although I'm not sure if it's located within the Mushroom Kingdoom or if its an independent country.

Super Mario Galaxy [1](http://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_Galaxy) and [2](http://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_Galaxy_2) introduces many new planets, and by extension many new kingdoms/land/countries/bakeries/et cetera as well. Unless the Mushroom Kingdom recently became a galactic empire, I think it's safe to say all of these planets are located outside the Mushroom Kingdom.

[Mario is Missing](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_is_Missing!) takes place..well, all over the planet earth. The first [Mario Golf](http://www.mariowiki.com/NES_Open_Tournament_Golf) game takes place on the planet Earth as well. There's also the [Donkey Kong games](http://www.mariowiki.com/Donkey_Kong#Donkey_Kong), which was likely intended to take place in Earth as well (I don't think the Mushroom Kingdom was even conceived until Super Mario Brothers).

[Paper Mario](http://www.mariowiki.com/Paper_Mario) introduces the land of Star Haven, and [Wario Land: Shake it!](http://www.mariowiki.com/Wario_Land:_Shake_It!) introduces the [Shake Dimension](http://www.mariowiki.com/Shake_Dimension).

I'm sure there are more I've missed, but as you can see, there's a lot more to the Mario Universe than just the Mushroom Kingdom.

Comment: Considering that the constituent parts of Sarasaland are "kingdoms", and the "Lands" of Mario 3, presumably all part of the mushroom kingdom, each have their own king, leads to only one conclusion: In the Mario universe, a princess outranks a king.

Answer (score 4):

And we can't forget [Nimbus Land](http://www.mariowiki.com/Nimbus_Land), the misleadingly named cloud kingdom from [Super Mario RPG, Legend of the Seven Stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_RPG), ruled by King and Queen Nimbus and

> usurped by the evil and vain Valentina.

Comment: Why is it misleading?

Comment: @OrangeDog Because its name include "Land" -- but it's not on land.  :)

Comment: Eh, the (*spoiler*) was a joke. The real spoiler is that the Cloud Kingdom exists at all, due to the fluffiness of a certain protagonist.

Answer (score 2):

In Mario and Luigi Dream Team, we go to Pi'llo Kingdom.

Answer (score 1):

Bowser is the Koopa King (or King of Koopas, if you prefer) and has his own castle with subjects that he rules over.  Though Super Mario 3 shows us a large, spooky, highly-militarized "world" that Bowser rules over, it is referred to as "Dark Land" and not as a Kingdom of its own.

However, Bowser is the only known actual **king*** in the main Mario series, outside of RPGs and sports games, so if anyone qualifies for ruling over a Kingdom, it'd be him.

*King Bob-Omb and King Goomba are both trapped in paintings, so whether or not they actually exist is...questionable.

Comment: Whomp King exists in SMG2, so the painting excuse from his SM64 appearance doesn’t hold.

Comment: @DonielF I didn't actually mention Whomp King, but that's true.  It's not entirely clear if they're even the same person (or how paintings work precisely), but Whomp King could very well be an actual King - complete with a fortress.

Answer (score 1):

In Super Mario Odyssey we’re introduced to the Cap, Cascade, Sand, Lake, Wooded, Cloud, Lost, Metro, Snow, Seaside, Luncheon, Bowser’s, and Moon Kingdoms.

Answer (score 0):

Super Mario World for the SNES takes place in Dinosaur Land.   Mario, Luigi, and Princess Peach go there on vacation and King Koopa kidnaps the Princess again.