# Is there any other kingdom than Hyrule?

Tags: legend-of-zelda-series

In the same vein as my other question [Is there any other kingdom than the Mushroom Kingdom?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220314/is-there-any-other-kingdom-than-the-mushroom-kingdom), we all know that Zelda is the Princess of Hyrule, but is there any other kingdoms visited during Link's adventures? What territories seen in the games are not in the Hyrule 'Kingdom' (thinking about it, I've never heard it mentionned as a kingdom)

What are the limits of Hyrule, and what is over them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there are places other than Hyrule kingdom.

#### [Koholint Island](http://zeldawiki.org/Koholint_Island)

An island which Link visits during the events of *Link's Awakening* and is quite separate from Hyrule. While there *is* a castle on Koholint Island, it belongs to a nobleman, and not to a king.

#### [The Sacred Realm / Dark World](http://zeldawiki.org/Dark_World)

First introduced in *A Link to the Past*, the Dark World exists in a dimension parallel to Hyrule and is a corrupted version of the Sacred Realm (where the Triforce rests). Despite being called a "realm", it does not seem to have a ruler, and therefore cannot really be called a kingdom.

#### [Termina](http://zeldawiki.org/Termina)

Termina is where *Majora's Mask* takes place. It is considered a parallel world to Hyrule due to its stark resemblance to the Kingdom. Termina is split in 5 areas: the swamps, home to the Deku Scrubs and their king; the mountains, home to the Gorons and their elder; the ocean, where the Zoras live; the Ikana Canyon, where the Ikana kingdom once stood; and Clock Town, which is ruled by a mayor.

#### [Labrynna](http://zeldawiki.org/Labrynna)

The setting for *Oracle of Ages*, it is one of few places that ***aren't*** a parallel version of Hyrule one way or another. While Labrynna is no longer a kingdom, it used to be 400 years before the events of the game. Link can actually visit Labrynna kingdom by travelling to the past using the Harp of Ages.

#### [Holodrum](http://zeldawiki.org/Holodrum)

Where *Oracle of Seasons* takes place. Similar to Labrynna, it is another place that is no parallel version of Hyrule. Holodrum is mostly uninhabited. Below Holodrum is [**Subrosia**](http://zeldawiki.org/Subrosia), whose Subrosian population does not seem to have a ruler.

#### [The Twilight Realm](http://zeldawiki.org/Twilight_Realm)

*Twilight Princess*' parallel version of Hyrule is home to the descendants of a people that have been banned from Hyrule a long time ago. Ruled by a Twili royal family, it can be considered a kingdom.

#### [Skyloft](http://zeldawiki.org/Skyloft)

While floating above what will eventually be known as Hyrule, it is difficult to say if *Skyward Sword*'s starting town does belong to Hyrule kingdom or not. Skyloft isn't ruled by a king, however.

#### [Lorule](http://zeldawiki.org/Lorule)

Often confused with the Dark World, Lorule is ***not*** *A Link Between Worlds*' version of the Dark World. It is instead *yet another* parallel version of Hyrule. Ruled by its own version of Hyrule's royal family with its own "Princess Hilda", it is as much a kingdom as Hyrule is.

#### [Hytopia](http://zeldawiki.org/Hytopia)

Since I haven't played *Tri Force Heroes*, I do not know the relationship between Hyrule and Hytopia. All I know, is that they aren't the same place. Hytopia is currently ruled by King Tuft, whose daughter is called Princess Styla.

Comment: Don't forget [Subrosia](http://zeldawiki.org/Subrosia).

Comment: @Michaellogg. Thanks, I added Subrosia under Holodrum.

Comment: There's also New Hyrule from Spirit Tracks which is set 100 years after Phantom Hourglass (which is in turn set immediately after Wind Waker).  We know it's not the same Hyrule because you visit old Hyrule Castle in Wind Waker.

Answer (score 1):

**The Great Sea/ Realm of the Ocean King**

Both are massive water worlds filled with islands in which Link's method of transportation is by boat rather then horse. The former is the primary setting of Wind Waker. It has no ruler, and was a result of a great flood as a last resort by the gods to stop Ganon when the hero of time was not there. The latter is the setting of its direct sequel, Phantom Hourglass, on the DS. The world in that game is overlooked by Oshus.

Comment: Hyrule is located under the Great Sea and the Realm of the Ocean King is implied to be connected to Koholint Island as the Ocean King is heavily implied to be the Wind Fish.

Comment: @Powerlord I think it's okay to say the Great Sea (Wind Waker's setting) is a different "kingdom". It doesn't appear to have a unified ruler, and as you stated, Hyrule is *beneath* the Great Sea, implying what's above is a separate realm. Unfortunately I'm not as familiar with the Realm of the Ocean King so I can't say for sure on that one.